# Storing Randomly Generated TextView Items to use with Copy to Clipboard Button

Tags: java, android, arrays, button, methods

I am coding in java and xml in the android studio.I have declared three arrays and I have declared three TextViews that will display randomly selected strings from each array.

I am new to programming and I need help with:

- a method that picks a random string from each array
- a button that sets the selcted strings to the TextViews
- a button that takes the text in the TextViews and copies them to clipboard

Here's my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] listOne = new String[]{...};
String[] listTwo = new String[]{...};
String[] listThree = new String[]{...};
public TextView view1;
public TextView view2;
public TextView view3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    view2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    view3= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3)
    int listOneInt = new Random().nextInt(listOne.length);
    int listTwoInt = new Random().nextInt(listTwo.length);
    int listThreeInt = new Random().nextInt(listThree.length);;
}

public void generate(View view)
{

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps (Except for copying to clipboard part, sorry don't know about that)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String[] listOne = new String[]{"Hello","world","123"};
String[] listTwo = new String[]{"stack","over","flow"};
String[] listThree = new String[]{"do","it","yourself"};

public TextView view1;
public TextView view2;
public TextView view3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    view2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    view3= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Random r = new Random();
    final String randOne;
    final String randTwo;
    final String randThree;

    int listOneInt = r.nextInt(listOne.length);
    int listTwoInt = r.nextInt(listTwo.length);
    int listThreeInt = r.nextInt(listThree.length);

    randOne = listOne[listOneInt];
    randTwo = listTwo[listTwoInt ];
    randThree = listThree[listThreeInt ];

    //Assuming you have a button with id assignRand
    Button assignRandToView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assignRand);
    assignRandToView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            view1.setText(randOne);
            view2.setText(randTwo);
            view3.setText(randThree);
        }
    });
}
}
```